# Sort JSON values by their value

Tags: php, json, sorting, foreach

Here is my JSON file:

```
    {
"example": "1",
"example2": 2,
"text": "3",
"info": {
    "agent": 4,
    "sum": 5,
    "collection": [{
        "Name": "6",
        "Pic": "7"
    }, {
        "Name": "8",
        "Pic": "9"
    }, {
        "Name": "10",
        "Pic": "11"
    }]
     }

      }
```

I display the results of the `JSON` file in a foreach loop:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://linktojson.com'));
foreach($data->info->collection as $key){

    echo $key->Pic;
    echo $key->Name;

  }
```

As you can see, 'Pic' has different numbers. How would I use `sort()` to make the largest number display at the top of the foreach loop and the lowest display at the bottom?

Comment: array_multisort did this work for you

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `array_multisort` here. [Check Online](https://3v4l.org/1jh0u)

```
$json = '{
"example": "1",
"example2": 2,
"text": "3",
"info": {
    "agent": 4,
    "sum": 5,
    "collection": [{
        "Name": "6",
        "Pic": "7"
        }, {
            "Name": "8",
            "Pic": "9"
        }, {
            "Name": "10",
            "Pic": "11"
        }]
     }
}';

$result = json_decode ($json, true);
foreach($result  as $key => $value){
    if($key == 'info'){
        $keys = array_keys($value['collection']);
        array_multisort(
            array_column($value['collection'], 'Pic'), SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $value['collection'], $keys
        );
        $value = array_combine($keys, $value['collection']);
        foreach($value as $val){
            echo $val['Pic']." - ".$val['Name']."<br/>";
        }
    }   
}
```

Result:

```
11 - 10
9 - 8
7 - 6
```

Comment: No, you don't: `usort($data->info->collection, function ($a, $b) { return $a->Pic - $b->Pic; })`. (Or perhaps with `$a` and `$b` reversed, I tend to forget.)

Comment: is this answer correct?

Comment: Why not???? Where is the problem?

Comment: OP use `Pic - name` and i use `Name - pic`, I need to update.

Comment: This answer may not be incorrect, but it's overly complicated when `usort` would be *much* simpler.

Comment: I don't know why but this answer doesn't display any JSON results. is there a way to debug it?

Comment: @deceze, The answer is correct, And there is a lots of way to do this, I use `arraymulti_sort` here.

Comment: Check the online example: [https://3v4l.org/1jh0u](https://3v4l.org/1jh0u)

Comment: @bobjomes, You need to check the online example...